# UIImages drawn at method return

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an IBAction that sets 49 images. The images are only set at the end of the method and not one by one. Why exactly does it do this? How would I make the images set one by one, rather than all at once at the end of the method. There is a 1.4 sec hang and then all images are set instantly.

Comment: Probably because it is not a trivial action (cpu wise) to load 49 images.  The display isn't refreshed after every change.  When you call your method, it's going to load all the data before actually refreshing anything.  There are probably more than a few ways you can do things differently to avoid this effect.  The first thing that comes to mind is loading an image in the background, then setting it on the main thread, then continue loading the next in the background, and so on.  Might not be the best solution for you though, it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matt's suggestion that you should load your images in a background thread, e.g. something like

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    for ( /* loop through my images */ )
    {
         // do whatever you need to do to load image (e.g. create your UIImageView, myImageView) 

         // now submit it to the main queue to be displayed, in this case, adding it to the scrollview that I use to hold all of my image thumbnails

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [self.scrollView addSubview:myImageView];
         });
    }

});
```

Note, the adding of the created UIImageView is submitted back to the main queue, as all UI updates have to happen on that main queue.